# Regex - Append text to the 'src' field of youtube link

Tags: asp.net, regex, vb.net, youtube

I have the following string -

```
<iframe width="425" height="349" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/8tPnX7OPo0Q" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

I need to add the following text to the end of the 'src' field - `?wmode=transparent` - so that the final string looks like below -

```
<iframe width="425" height="349" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/8tPnX7OPo0Q?wmode=transparent" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Can anyone advise me how to do this using regex in asp.net...I have only replaced text using regex before.

---

I have tried the below code but I am unfamliar... can anyone advise me of what am I doing wrong ?

```
Dim test As String = "<iframe width=""425"" height=""349""
   src=""http://www.youtube.com/embed/8tPnX7OPo0Q"" frameborder=""0"" allowfullscreen>
</iframe>"

Dim regex1 As Regex = New Regex("src=(['""])(https?:\/\/[^ >]*?youtu\.?be[^ >]+?)(?=\1)")
Dim match1 As String = regex1.Replace(test, "src=\1\2?wmode=transparent")
```

Comment: I believe there's a DOM parser you can use instead of regexes.

Comment: Why do you need Regex? Can you not simply concatenate it?

Answer (score 1):

Find RegEx: `src=(['"])(https?:\/\/[^ >]*?youtu\.?be[^ >]+?)(?=\1)`
Replace with: `src=\1\2?wmode=transparent`
Explained demo here: http://regex101.com/r/bK8hC6

Note: This will allow both `youtube.com` and `youtu.be` domain names

**Update:**

Implementation:

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

...

Dim output As String = Regex.Replace(test, 
    "src=(['"])(https?:\/\/[^ >]*?youtu\.?be[^ >]+?)(?=\1)", 
    "src=\1\2?wmode=transparent")
```

Comment: sorry i see i should have used the edit link on my original post as i have a question and not a comment